# How to observe a property of items in collection with ReactiveUI

Tags: c#, reactiveui

My team uses ReactiveUI and I want to try using its APIs when the property in one item in a ObservableCollection changes:

I have a ViewModel deriving from ReactiveObject with this property:

```
public class ViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    public bool PageEnabled { get; set; } // the actual implementation uses custom logic, a backing field and raises PropertyChanged accordingly
}
```

And there's another property in a parent view model which I try to subscribe to like this:

```
public class ParentViewModel : ReacitveObject
{
    public ObservableCollection<ViewModel> DocumentPages { get; set; }

    public ParentViewModel()
    {
        DocumentPages.ToObservableChangeSet(vm => vm.PageEnabled).Subscribe(changeSet => UpdateSelection());
    }
}
```

Tl;dr: whenever the PageEnabled property changes in any of the items in that collection, I want to execute the aforementioned UpdateSelection method. However, the subscription I've attempted and pasted here doesn't invoke that method when the PageEnabled property changes. The method is only called a couple of times when the VM is initialilzing, but that's not enough.

My question is, how do I get the UpdateSelection to be called when the PageEnabled property changes?

(I'm aware I can manually subscribe/unsubscribe to the PropertyChanged event whenever an item is added/removed from the DocumentPagese collection, but according to ReactiveUI's documentation https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/collections/ it should be possible to do this in a more declarative manner, yet that doesn't seem to work.)

Comment: Have you tried `.AutoRefresh(x => x.PageEnabled)` by the way?

Comment: I did now, now that I had time to work on that code again. AutoRefresh worked. I actually didn't know about that method, so thanks.